# Can there be more than one program for bubblesort?

Tags: c

okay so i am working with different sorting methods in C.
the most basic one is "Bubble Sort"
So the basic definition of bubble sort is swapping two consecutive boxes in an array depending upon which way you want to sort them.
there are a total of "n elements" that are checked to swap "n-1" times and the compiler runs the function one more time in the end to check if the sorting is done correctly so the time complexity is O(n^2).

while making the program, i figured that this type of sorting can be done in two ways. My questions are:-

> If the Both of the program can be considered bubble sort?
>   if Not then why?
>   I think the time complexity in both the cases is same. If i am wrong, Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int n;
        printf("Enter the size of Array: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n];
        int i;
        printf("Enter The Elements Of Array:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                int j;
                for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
                {
                        if (a[j] < a[j-1])
                        {
                                int temp;
                                temp=a[j];
                                a[j]=a[j-1];
                                a[j-1]=temp;
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("\n\nSorted Array Is:  ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                printf("%d  ",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int n;
        printf("Enter The Size Of Array: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n],i;
        printf("Enter The Elements Of Array:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        int temp;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
                {
                        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                        {
                                temp=a[j];
                                a[j]=a[j+1];
                                a[j+1]=temp;
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("Sorted Array Is: ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                printf("%d  ", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

> In The First Program, The swapping is taking place from the end part.
>   The Bigger number is being pushed to the front one by one.
>   In the Second Program, The Swapping is taking place from the front.
>   The Smaller number is being pushed towards the end one by one

Comment: it doesn't matter whether you swap from start to end or from end to start

Comment: This is wrong though: `int temp[n]; temp[n]=a[j];`. You are indexing `temp` out of bounds. You don't need a temp array to swap two ints. A temp int will suffice.

Comment: See [Bubblesort - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and the external link [Sorting in the Presence of Branch Prediction and Caches](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/publications/tech-reports/reports.05/TCD-CS-2005-57.pdf) for an in-depth discussion of sort algorithms.

Comment: ah yeah, made a mistake there. my bad. i just corrected that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, yes, barring subtle bugs, both of these are bubble sorts. There's nothing special about which way the bubbling goes; most implementations bubble "up" from left to right, but there is no hard and fast rule that bans bubbling "down" from right to left.

As a general rule, if the question is "Is there more than one way to do it?", in programming, the answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not Bubble Sort. Bubble Sort looks like this:

```
do {
   sorted = true
   sweep through the array, swapping adjacent elements into sorted order
   if we swap any elements, set sorted = false
} while (sorted == false)
```

The true Bubble Sort doesn't have an outer limit with a fixed number of iterations, and it doesn't have an inner loop that performs fewer operations with increasing numbers of iterations of the outer loop.  Yes; those design aspects are silly, but that's what Bubble Sort is.

There is a more serious algorithm related to Bubble Sort called Insertion Sort. Insertion sort is this:

```
dest_array = []   // start with empty destination array
for each element in source_array
   insert element at appropriate spot in dest_array
```

Insertion Sort can be implemented within a single array. Originally the entire array consists of source_array[] and dest_array[] is a zero-length area at the end of source_array[]:

```
[...source_array...][] <- dest array
```

. We begin the sort by removing an element *e* of source_array[] right at the boundary where dest_array[] starts:

```
[...source_array...][e][]   <- [e] is removed from source_array

[...source_array...][   ]   <- dest_array acquires an empty spot

[...source-array...][e]     <- [e] is inserted into dest_array, in order
```

We keep repeating this: `source_array` keeps shrinking, and the sorted `dest_array` grows, until it takes up the entire space.

Insertion Sort has a structure resembling your code: a triangular iteration with an outer loop that has a fixed number of iterations corresponding to the  number of elements, and an inner loop which gets longer (since `dest_array` grows longer). Inserting each element into the correct spot in `dest_array` can be carried out by a series of swaps of adjacent elements.

**What you have implemented is called Selection Sort.** You're repeatedy selecting the highest (or lowest) element of the remaining `source_array` partition and moving it to the end, thereby building up the `dest_array` partition in order.  You have two variations of Selection Sort: repeatedly moving the highest element into the upper partition, or repeatedly moving the lowest item into a lower partition. Either way, that upper or lower partition will take over the entire array, leaving it sorted.

Selection Sort, Insertion Sort and Bubble Sort are distinct algorithms. Bubble Sort is a kind of joke on the other two. There is never any reason to implement Bubble Sort instead of Selection or Insertion sort. These two are respectable: they have their uses, like sorting a small number of things in a tiny space. (Say you had to sort some small table of values in a tiny piece of boot loader machine code or whatever.)